# Angular @Input inheritance causing weird compilation error with ng-packagr

Tags: angular, angular7, ng-packagr

I am experiencing a really obscure error message in Angular 7 when trying to use `@Input` inheritance. The error message does not make any sense because I have 1 mandatory `@Input` and 2 optional `@Input` so the math don't add up...

```
Directive MyComponent, Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/project/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ngc/compile-source-files.js:53:68)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/project/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ngc/compile-source-files.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/project/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ngc/compile-source-files.js:3:12)
    at Object.compileSourceFiles (/home/project/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ngc/compile-source-files.js:19:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/project/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ng-v5/entry-point/ts/compile-ngc.transform.js:26:32)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/project/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ng-v5/entry-point/ts/compile-ngc.transform.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

I have created this reduced test case (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1r1mn)... that's represent what I am trying to do, if i compile reduced test case with `ng-packagr`, everything compiled fine without throwing any errors... but in my actual project (also uses `ng-packagr`) it does not work and throws the above error...

If I remove the `@Input` from the base class and shift it up to the child class, then everything works fine... however with angular 7, `@Input` inheritance shouldn't be a problem.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to troubleshoot this error? :(

Added sample template code... The error is definitely NOT the template. As you can see I just pass 1 argument to it, but somehow it is "expecting 2", I don't know where or how it can even expect 2 arguments. I don't know a good way to debug this.

```
<div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="gridConfig">
        <my-ag-grid [config]="gridConfig"></my-ag-grid>
        <my-component [config]="myPluginConfig"></my-component>
     </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the 'directive' used by MyComponent does not match the argument signature.

Adding the MyComponent template code will help others answer. :)

Comment: Pretty sure is not in the template, I've added a sample template code. Is basically quite similar of what you will find in my stackblitz sample.

Comment: I can't see 'directive' I checked app.module.ts.
But i couldn't find the 'directive'.

Comment: Check out the directive you're using.
It looks like you can't track errors with non-equal code.
This seems to be a very sensitive issue.

Comment: That's the thing, I am not even using directive... is a component (exactly like in my stackblitz). Also my code ran fine in `ng serve`, just that `ng-packagr` compiling it.

Answer (score 0):

OH MY F*** GOD. So the problem was because I have the following in my component:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
stuffClicked($event, fromComponent) {
```

But the error message from `ng-packagr` is does not point to anything remotely close to this problem at all! `Directive MyComponent, Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.` is actually trying to tell me that, @HostListener is passing 1 argument but my `stuffClicked` function is expecting 2 arguments. This looks like a `ng-packagr` bug.

Anyhow, to by pass the issue, is simply to make the second argument optional `fromComponent?`.